# gcloud docker -- push request canceled while waiting for connection

Tags: gcloud, docker-registry

Trying to push docker image to gcloud and started getting this error.

gcloud docker -- push us.gcr.io/purple01-192114/purple_cloud:80only
The push refers to repository [us.gcr.io/purple01-192114/purple_cloud]
Get https://us.gcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

This image is on my local machine 
C:\Users\john_>docker images
REPOSITORY                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
us.gcr.io/purple01-192114/purple_cloud   80only              a10a04043cc6        12 hours ago        711MB
node                                     9.4                 c888d933885c        8 days ago          676MB

Gcloud main console reports "No sign of any errors."

container registry for this project is empty.  I had quite a few, but these were deleted when I started experiencing this error.

I don't see any limits being passed on my trial account.

Any suggestion on where to look would be appreciated.

---

update
1) disable virus program on local machine did not help
2) built and pushed from gcloud console and it worked.

So I'm suspecting something on my local machine changed.  Still would like suggestions for what to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Restarted docker and it now works.